# Consider the graph of $ \ f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} (f(x)) \ $ , which is continuous on the closed interval $ \ [-1.5,1.5] \ $

Tags: calculus

Consider the graph of $ \ f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} (f(x)) \ $ , which is continuous on the closed interval $ \ [-1.5,1.5] \ $.

[image]

Then choose the **correct options** from the below questions:

(i) $ f(x) \ $ has   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1.25,-1) \ $

(ii) $ f(x) \ $ has   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1,0) \ $

(iii) $ f(x) \ $ has   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (1,1.25) \ $

(iv) $ f''(x) \ $ is   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1.25,-1) \ $

(v) $ f''(x) \ $ has   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1,0) \ $

(vi) $ f''(x) \ $ has   $ \ positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined   \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (1,1.25) \ $

**Answer:**

(i) Since $ \ f'(x) \ $ is positive on the interval $ \ (-1.25,-1) \ $ , we conclude that

$ f(x) \ $  has  $ \ Positive \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1.25,-1) \ $

(ii) Similarly,

$ f(x) \ $ has $ \ positive \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (-1,0) \ $

(iii)

$ f(x) \ $  has  $  \  positive \ $ slope on the interval $ \ (1,1.25) \ $

**Am I so far Right?**

Help me with at least the solution.

Comment: Yep! Because $f'$ is the slope, if $f' > 0$, then $f(x)$ has a positive slope. And then, you'll have to examine the slope of $f'(x)$ to find (iv), (v), and (vi). For example: (d)- The slope of $f'$ is positive, so $f''$ is positive because $f''$ represents the slope of $f'$.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley - you didn't read the questions for (iv)-(vi) carefully enough. They don't ask if $f''$ is positive or negative, but rather whether $f''$ has positive or negative slope (though a wording error in (iv) does muddy the waters a bit, but I assume it should be phrased like the rest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Christopher Marley has noted, your first three answers are correct. To get other three, note that they do not mention $f(x)$ itself, so instead of thinking of them as talking about $f(x)$, you should consider them as talking about a function that just happens to be called $f'(x)$.

I.e., if we let $g(x) = f'(x)$, then we can rephrase these three questions in terms of $g(x)$:

(iv) $g'(x)$ has $positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined$ slope on the interval $(-1.25,-1)$

(v) $g'(x)$ has $positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined$ slope on the interval $(-1,0)$

(vi) $g'(x)$ has $positive / Negative / Zero / Undefined$ slope on the interval $(1,1.25)$

To figure out the slope of $g'(x)$, note that the slope of $g'(x)$ is $g''(x)$. Then go back and review what your calculus book says about what the 2nd derivative tells you about the original function (and vice versa).

Comment: Yes, I certainly did not see the part about slope. It's positive, but the positive slope itself is decreasing, so (iv) would be negative (right?)

Comment: @ChristopherMarley - yes.